# Freemarker: call a static util method from a template file (*.ftl)

Tags: freemarker

In a Freemarker FTL file, I want to call `StringUtils.capatilize(myString)`. For example:

```
<p>You selected ${selectionString}.</p>
<p>${StringUtils.capatilize(selectionString)} is great.</p>
```

Can I somehow *import* `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't `#import` a class, only other templates.

Note that you can achieve a similar result with `#assign StringUtils=statics['org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils']`, as far as you add `objectWrapper.getStaticModels()` as `statics` to the set of shared variables in the `Configuration` or add it to the data-model.

Answer (score 18):

First, add these code to your `Controller`:

```
BeansWrapper wrapper = new BeansWrapper(new Version(2,3,27));
TemplateModel statics = wrapper.getStaticModels();
model.addAttribute("statics", statics);
```

And then, in your `.ftl` file, define the class like this:

```
<#assign YourUtilClass=statics['com.springboot.util.YourUtilClass']>
```

(The path including in `['']` is the class' path)
Finally, you can access your static method like this:

```
${YourUtilClass.yourMethod(someParams)}
```

Comment: It worked awesomely! 2 additional notes: 1 - Do not wrap into `${}` when accessing the static method in the expression: `<#if Util.booleanCheck(field)>`. 2 - Your class and method should be **public**.