# Freemarker: call a static util method from a template file (*.ftl) when no controller

Tags: java, freemarker

I need to add the following static method in my ftl template.

${statics["java.util.UUID"].randomUUID()}

I don't have a controller class as per the following link

[Freemarker: call a static util method from a template file (*.ftl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082563/freemarker-call-a-static-util-method-from-a-template-file-ftl/67814644#67814644)

Any other solution to add a static method in the FTL template?

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve that purely in the template. Actually, it depends on what other "backdoors" the data-model exposes to the template, but in general you can't do that by design.

If you can add Java classes to the class-path, then by default (otherwise depending on security settings) you can use `'com.example.MyClass'?new()` to instantiate a `TemplateMethodModel` implementation that calls what you need. So there you didn't modify the controller. But still need to be able to add Java classes.